# Change "before" behaviour

Tags: css, mouseevent, css-animations

I'm trying to cleanup after another developer and came across the following CSS animations. How might I change it to click instead of roll-over? I'm not sure what 'hover' in this case is called in terms of CSS to look for alternatives.

```
   #subscription-dashboard:before {
        ...
    }

#subscription-dashboard:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
          ...
}
        #subscription-dashboard:after {
    left: -80px;
    top: 145px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
              ...
}
#subscription-dashboard:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
             ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you are after is "pseudo-class"

To handle clicks, you can change `:hover` to `:active`, which will trigger when the mouse button is clicked. This doesn't emulate a click completely unfortunately, as releasing the mouse button will revert back to the normal class; for that, you could use something similar to:

```
transition-delay: 1000000s;
```

on one of the classes to delay - for a very very long time - the restoration back to the non-`:active` class.

Comment: Ah, good point about the delay. i'm trying to add them to the 'after' definitions. I might have to go back to javascript though, because functionally it has to change to a toggle (maintain state opened or closed) instead of show x on rollover.

Comment: You may be able to use the checkbox hack (http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) here if you want to avoid JavaScript. But, I say that with the caveat that I've not tried it myself.

Comment: WOW. I'm already a JS purist, so seeing something like that takes me aback. HTML/CSS != a good state machine...

Comment: If it helps, I only learnt about it today, as a follow-up from a talk by an ex-W3Cer.